# generate XML file in python for regedit

Tags: xml, python-2.7

What can I do if I want to create an XML file in python to display software name and version?

```
   for i in range (50):

        try:
            subkey=EnumKey(akey,i)
            asubkey = OpenKey(akey, subkey)
            #print subkey

            val=QueryValueEx(asubkey,"DisplayName")
            var=QueryValueEx(asubkey,"DisplayVersion")

            #print val
            #print var

            if val != '' and var != '':


                the_doc = ROOT(
                    DOC(
                        Name(val, DisplayName='Name'),
                        Version(var, DisplayVersion='Version')
                        )
                    )


                f.write(lxml.etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=False))
            else:
                print "Registry empty"
        except:
            print " "

    f.close()
except:
    print "File not available"
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to generate xml file in python i took before for loop try statement     and f = open('file.xml', 'w') but nothing to happen.... can u suggest what to do.

Comment: Use the "edit" link and add the missing code to your question.  I'd add 'python' tag too in addition to 'python-2.7'.  Also, please elaborate on "but nothing happened".    You want to provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem in order to facilitate getting help.  Thanks.